# Use Global Resource file in external js file using jquery

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, .net

I 'm devleloping web application using .NET. Here i m facing 1 issue.I want to get value from global resource file in external .js file. If any one knows the solution can help me.,

Thanks in advance
Jey

Answer (score 1):

Just as an solution, you can make web service on web application side, that will return localization value for key in request. And then you can get it via Ajax from your external js file.

Or other way is to generate needed localization values as javascript variables during page rendering, and then you can use it in the same page.

Comment: No i want with out any postback.,

Comment: Then second way with generation localization values on page during rendering should be ok for you, as it will be done at page generation stage

Comment: I want to hide values in page and to use that values in js file. Can u suggest anything like that?

Comment: Even in that case these values would be accessibly by anyone who knows how to open Browser Developer Tools. But you can make WebService that will generate new javascript file with these values, and will return it. And then you can add link to that WebService to your page

Comment: How can i hide the values in js file?

Comment: You can't hide any value in javascript, as Browser will execute it, and it should know about it. There is obfuscation for Javascript, but it won't help for string values